# What is the meaning of the medieval word 'bliant', used to describe a fabric?

Tags: middle-ages, fashion, wales

There are a number of references to "bliant" in [The Mabinogion](http://www.everymanslibrary.co.uk/classics-author.aspx?letter=m&search=&firstname=The&surname=Mabinogion), but I cannot track the word down using my trusty Webster's Unabridged or Google (I get baby names, etc). Can anyone help?
For example, in *The Lady of the Fountain* we have "...cushions a-plenty with covers of red bliant...", "...and of bliant was the table napery...", "...an ensign of pure black bliant...". Bliant always appears i the company of silk, so I assume it was an expensive but durable fabric.

Comment: A quick google turns up a couple of references (but not particularly authoritative) that suggest "bliant" means linen.

Comment: For example, "Fine linen, as cambric or lawn", according to https://www.google.com/books/edition/Archaeologia_Cambrensis/nbQVAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=bliant&pg=PA96&printsec=frontcover

Comment: Patricia Williams, "Dress and Dignity in the *Mabinogion*". In: Robin Netherton and Gale R. Owen-Crocker (eds.), *Medieval Clothing and Textiles, Volume 8*, Boydell Press 2012, pp. 83-114. On page 95: "None of the citations in which these items occur actually distinguishes precisely what fibre *bliant* was. The towels and tablecloth suggest linen, but the other items could have been silk or even fine wool."

Comment: @njuffa Thank you. Your comment could stand as an answer.

Comment: @SimonCrase I am considering it but am conflicted. My expertise in this area is exactly zero. I don't know whether what I quoted is in fact the prevailing expert opinion.

Comment: @njuffa I've been thinking about your comment, and I wonder whether *bliant* might be a technique rather then an actual thread. *Silk* is a thread and a fabric, but *satin* is a weaving technique, and the product is also called "satin". So *maybe* a *bliant* ensign, or cushion cover was woven using an expensive, high status process.

Comment: @SimonCrase That seems like plausible speculation. A note along the same lines is found on the [page](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Medieval_Clothing_and_Textiles/mK5nF2Wst3oC?hl=en&gbpv=1) I pointed to: " *Heather Rose Jones speculates that "it is also possible that the word meant a particular weight or weave of both silk and linen in Welsh contexts."* "

Comment: "bliant" is not listed in the full OED.

Comment: professional historian girlfriend suggests you check alternate spellings - bileaux or something like that -

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A [Pocket Dictionary Welsh to English by William Richards](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/19704/19704-h/19704-h.htm) published in 1861 lists Bliant as "fine linen, cambric".